# Custom View not showing in android

Tags: android

I have a custom view defined in android. I have set it in layout in such a way that initially the layout has 0dp width and when a button is triggered I animate the layout and increase its width but the problem is that my custom view won't show when I show the layout though its there. What a strange behaviour :S

**EDIT**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/PieControlLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@null"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout                 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel
                android:id="@+id/wheel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

            </com.digitalaria.gama.wheel.Wheel>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Because the width is 0 so its not displayed. Instead of you have to set 0 dp for height

Comment: height and width of what ?

Comment: <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/PieControlLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: Is your `LinearLayout` nested inside another `LinearLayout`? Either way, your `layout_weight` should not be 0.

Comment: that is what I must do in order to animate the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had to recall the initialization function of my custom view after animation finished. Thanks for the support everyone